# How to reconstruct a polynomial given $P(a),P(2a),P(3a),...$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, polynomials

Consider $P(x)=a_nx^n+\ldots + a_0$  a polynomial of $\deg(P)=n$.

We may reconstruct $P$ using $n+1$ independent equations, in particular, when we  $P(a), P(2a),\ldots, P((n+1)a)$ are given for some $a \neq 0$.

I know $a_n$ can be easily obtained by the *Difference Sequences* (See for example [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136020402)), but how to obtain the other terms explicitly?

One idea is to translate the problem in the language of Vandermond, but the inverse of Vandermond is a challenge itself. Does someone have any idea?

Comment: Having obtained $a_n$ from difference sequences, you can subtract $a_nx^n$ from the values and do the difference sequence again to get $a_{n-1}$ and so on.  There are ways to use the original difference table to get all the terms, but I do not know them.

Comment: Vandermond as in the matrix? yes, it will give you a solution

Comment: @RossMillikan I know but this recurrence form is is not easy to work with.

Answer (score 4):

Your idea to use the Vandermonde matrix does lead to a correct solution. The set up is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & a^2 & \dots &a^n \\
1 & 2a & (2a)^2 & \dots &(2a)^n \\
\vdots & \vdots&\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & (n+1)a & ((n+1)a)^2 & \dots & ((n+1)a)^n \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_0 \\ a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}P(a) \\ P(2a) \\ \vdots \\ P((n+1)a)\end{bmatrix} $$
The condition $a\neq 0$ guarantees that the Vandermonde matrix  is invertible.

Comment: For the inverse, see e.g. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde_Matrix

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $$P(x)=a_nx^n+\ldots + a_0$$ passes through points $(a,P(a)), (2a, P(2a)),.... ((n+1)a, P((n+1)a)$

We can use *Lagrange interpolation* to identify the polynomial  passing through these points.

We can also solve the  linear system of of $n+1$ equations with $n+1$ unknowns  to find the coefficients.